# ECS health check from container passed, but container was unresponsive

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

The other day, we came across an issue where one of the containers in our ECS Cluster was unresponsive.  The troubling part was that the instances health checks, administered via Docker, seemed to indicate that nothing was wrong.

In addition to ECS, we use Route53 service discovery, and all of our containers use these service entries to communicate.

For reference, [Docker health checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html) can be used by ECS to determine if a container should be replaced.  We use something like the following (pseudo code):

```
HEALTHCHECK curl localhost:3000 ... more docker params here
```

When the incident occurred, connections to the container were timing out, but I could see in the task logs that the health checks were completing successfully.  I even tried logging into Cloud9 instance in the VPC and connecting to the task, and was receiving these timeouts.  Nothing else seemed out of the ordinary.

All that was required to fix the issue was stopping the container in question.

How can this be avoided?  In an ideal situation, ECS should have detected that the container was inaccessible.  Is there a way to health check at the container level, AKA "can the container accept connections?", rather than just at the application level?

Comment: Move your health checks from docker to an ELB.

Comment: Is this the only way?  We do not use an ELB internally, partly due to this from the service discovery docs: "You can configure service discovery for an ECS service that is behind a load balancer, but service discovery traffic is always routed to the task and not the load balancer."  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html